# Xamarin Binding of Collection(Ljava/util/Collection)

Tags: facebook, xamarin, binding

I'm trying to map the FAcebook SDK to xamarin and I used the documentation for the binding.
Unfortunately I'm struggling with items like this one, where I have a collection of something as parameter.
the sdk has the following method header
`public final HttpURLConnection toHttpConnection(@NotNull Collection<GraphRequest> requests)` 
now I'm trying to map that in my xml file like this, but this fails :(

`<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook']/class[@name='GraphRequest.Companion']/method[@name='executeBatchAsync' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][starts-with(@type,'java.util.Collection&lt;GraphRequest&gt;')]]/parameter[1]" name="managedName">requests</attr>`

simple types are no problem

but when building I get the warning that this does not match any nodes.

Comment: Do you mean define the collection in xmal?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I was missing the correct package name for the type inside the collection. "com.facebook.GraphRequest"

`<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.facebook']/class[@name='GraphRequest.Companion']/method[@name='executeBatchAsync' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][starts-with(@type,'java.util.Collection&lt;com.facebook.GraphRequest&gt;')]]/parameter[1]" name="managedName">requests</attr>`